# How to workaround a polymer project build when google-chart is in use?

Tags: deployment, build, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

If in polymer project I add google-chart:
    `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html">`
and trying to `polymer build`, then I'm getting following error messages:
`error:   Promise rejection: Error: no resolver found for https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`

Looks like it is due to https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/261 issue.

Question is: how can I workaround this problem and successfully build project to deploy it to the web hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already resolved. Update your polymer cli will do.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/261

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the file `bower_components/google-chart/charts-loader.html` to point instead to `thisIsAReallyLongFileNameToUseAsABookmark.js`, and then create a file in `bower_components/google-chart/` called `thisIsAReallyLongFileNameToUseAsABookmark.js` so that it can properly resolve the file.

After the build you could search the file and swap it out to point to `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`.

If the build is instead merging the js file itself, you put something like this in the file, and then just replace it with a script tag to pull in the external script:

```
var thisIsAReallyLongVarToUseAsABookmark = undefined;
```

Yes this is a slightly convoluted method, but as I can't find any documentation to ignore a specific file or folder in polymer-build, it seems there may not be too many other options yet.